# Memory Issue in string C#

Tags: c#, string, garbage-collection

I have little test program

```
public class Test
{  
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

My console simply call Test class

```
class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
  Test t = new Test();
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Test.txt"))
  {
     t.Response = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }                       
  t.Response = t.Response.Substring(0, 5);

  Console.WriteLine(t.Response);
  Console.Read();
 }     
}
```

I have appox 60 MB data in my Test.txt file. When the program get executes, it is taking lot of memory because string is immutable. What is the better way handle this kind of scenario using string.

I know that i can use string builder. but i have created this program to replicate a scenario in one of my production application which uses string.

when i tried with GC.Collect(), memory is released immediately. I am not sure whether i can call GC in code.

Please help. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I think i did not explain it clearly. sorry for the confusion. 
I am just reading data from file to get huge data as don't want create 60MB of data in code. 
My pain point is below line of code where i have huge data in Response field.

t.Response = t.Response.Substring(0, 5);

Comment: Don't call GC.Collect() in code!   .NET will call  it when the OS start to get low on memory.

Comment: It can be called if some scenarios, but most of the time it is best to just leave it alone.

Answer (score 3):

You could limit your reads to a block of bytes (buffer). Loop through and read the next block into your buffer and write that buffer out. This will prevent a large chunk of data being stored in memory.

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Test.txt", true))
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        int idx = 0;
        while (reader.ReadBlock(buffer, idx, buffer.Length) > 0)
        {
            idx += buffer.Length;
            Console.Write(buffer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "block of bytes" is very painful suggestion when reading text files since you need to know encoding...

Comment: Well, char/byte whatever. The point is, the user was asking about reading in large files. The most efficient and least memory intensive way to do that is by a preset buffer instead of trying to absorb the entire file into memory. With StreamReader you can specify a parameter to look at byte order marks to determine encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Can you read your file line by line?  If so, I would recommend calling:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(path)
```

When you iterate this collection using

```
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    // do something with line
}
```

the collection will be iterated using lazy evaluation.  That means the entire contents of the file won't need to be kept in memory while you do something with each line.

Answer (score 0):

`StreamReader` provides just version of `Read` that you looking for - [Read(Char[], Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824(v=vs.110).aspx) - which lets you pick out first characters of the stream. Alternatively you can read char-by-char with regular `StreamReader.Read` till you decided that you have enough.

```
    var textBuffer = new char[5];
    reader.ReadToEnd(textBuffer, 0, 5); // TODO: check if it actually read engough
    t.Response = new string(textBuffer);
```

Note that if you know encoding of the stream you may use lower level reading as byte array and use `System.Text.Encoding` classes to construct strings with encoding yourself instead of relaying on `StreamReader`.